# Isomorphism between compact operators and compact operators tensor matrices ($\mathbb{K}\otimes M_n(\mathbb{C})\cong \mathbb{K}$)

Tags: tensor-products, operator-algebras, compact-operators

Let $\mathbb{K}$ be the compact operators and $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ the complex valued matrices. I have read the algebra $\mathbb{K}\otimes M_n(\mathbb{C})$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{K}$. Could you tell me the isomorphism?
I thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, we are assuming an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space $H$ here.

Since both $H$ and $H^n$ have the same dimension, there exists a unitary map $V:H\to H^n$. So we can define $\pi:B(H)\to B(H^n)$ by 
$$
\pi(T)=VTV^*.
$$ 
Since $V$ is a unitary, $\pi(T)$ is an injective $*$-homomorphism.

So it remains to show that $\pi(\mathbb K)=M_n(\mathbb K)$. If $T\in\mathbb K$, then $VTV^*$ is compact because pre and post-composition with a compact is compact. And if $T'\in B(H^n)$ is compact, then so is $V^*T'V\in \mathbb K$, and $\pi(V^*T'V)=T'$.

Comment: Question: why do we know there exists such a unitary map and why does it have to be unitary?

Comment: Unitaries are precisely the isomorphisms of Hilbert spaces. As written in the answer, $H$ and $H^n$ have the same dimension and so any function that maps an orthonormal basis of $H$ to an orthonormal basis of $H^n$ extends by linearity to a unitary.

Comment: I wonder how would I show injectivity of the map? Also do we need the injectivity in the second part of your proof somewhere, just out of curiosity? I find the map quite interesting because it comes up all over operator algebra theory. For example if I would define the map $\pi(T) = VT$, this would also be a map that forwards $T$ into $B(H^{n})$ but it would fail to be a injective *-homomorphism. So in a way this map is constructed in a way such that it is a injective *-homomorphism AND it forwards the map into $B(H^{n})$ right?

Comment: The map $T\longmapsto VT$ is in $B(H,H^n)$. That's why at the level of operators you use $VTV^*$, so that it maps $H^n\to H^n$. About injectivity, if you mean the injectivity of my $\pi$, conjugation by a unitary is always a bijection (properly, a $*$-isomorphism); if $VTV^*=0$, multiply by $V^*$ on the left and by $V$ on the right to get $T=0$.